# Add existing drawable animation onto main_activity.xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation

I created animation.xml file in the res/drawable/ in Android Studio.
It is working fine on that page. However, what I need is too add animation onto activity_main.xml where I have all the stuffs I built.

[image]

Being specific walking man photos(series of) in my `res/drawable/animation.xml` file and I want to import it next to buttons in main activity.

How can I import animation.xml in main activity so I can put it right next to the buttons of above UI.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it supposed to be a button? If so - you can use the setIcon(icon.png) method, another solution is to set it in your layout file.